# How can I count values that can be grouped by another columns in R

Tags: r

I'm still new to this R program and hanging around with this program. And I got a trouble with counting values.

I'm trying to count rows that can be grouped by another cols but I can't find ways.

My data is like this

```
CRP SSN PLT PARAM VAL
A   S01 1   GER   NA
A   S01 2   GER   NA
A   S01 1   VEG   40
A   S01 2   VEG   41
A   S02 1   GER   100
A   S02 2   GER   90
B   S03 1   GER   90
```

It has like this data frame and has 720obs. of 5 variables.
I have to count val but when I try to use aggregate or n() with group by, my result is not like what I want.

So the result that I want to get is

1. The number of VAL in same parameter(also in same SSN)
2. If there are any NA values than want to get counting result as "0".
   like:

```
    CRP SSN PARAM VAL_count
    A   S01 GER   0
    A   S01 VEG   2
    A   S02 GER   2
    B   S03 GER   1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sum` and `is.na` to count the row in each group.

```
library(dplyr)
result <- df %>% 
           group_by(CRP,SSN, PARAM) %>% 
           summarise(VAL_count = sum(!is.na(VAL)), .groups = 'drop')
result
#  CRP   SSN   PARAM VAL_count
#  <chr> <chr> <chr>     <int>
#1 A     S01   GER           0
#2 A     S01   VEG           2
#3 A     S02   GER           2
#4 B     S03   GER           1
```

We can also implement this in base R and `data.table`.

```
#Base R
aggregate(VAL~CRP + SSN + PARAM, df, function(x) sum(!is.na(x)), na.action = 'na.pass')

#data.table
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .(VAL_count = sum(!is.na(VAL))), .(CRP ,SSN ,PARAM)]
```

**data**

It is easier to help if you provide data in a [reproducible format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269)

```
df <- structure(list(CRP = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B"), SSN = c("S01", 
"S01", "S01", "S01", "S02", "S02", "S03"), PLT = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L), PARAM = c("GER", "GER", "VEG", "VEG", "GER", 
"GER", "GER"), VAL = c(NA, NA, 40L, 41L, 100L, 90L, 90L)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```

Comment: Thank you! I did almost done with aggregate but needed one step for that. And found it! Thanks to you, I can learn more about R functions

Answer (score 0):

```
library(tidyverse)

df = read.table(
  header = TRUE,text="
CRP SSN PLT PARAM VAL
A   S01 1   GER   NA
A   S01 2   GER   NA
A   S01 1   VEG   40
A   S01 2   VEG   41
A   S02 1   GER   100
A   S02 2   GER   90
B   S03 1   GER   90") %>% as_tibble()

df %>% group_by(CRP, SSN, PARAM) %>% 
  summarise(n = sum(!is.na(VAL)))
```

output

```
# A tibble: 4 x 4
# Groups:   CRP, SSN [3]
  CRP   SSN   PARAM     n
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <int>
1 A     S01   GER       0
2 A     S01   VEG       2
3 A     S02   GER       2
4 B     S03   GER       1
```

Answer (score 0):

We could use `aggregate` from `base R`

```
aggregate(cbind(VAL_count = !is.na(VAL)) ~ ., df[-3], FUN = sum)
  CRP SSN PARAM VAL_count
1   A S01   GER         0
2   A S02   GER         2
3   B S03   GER         1
4   A S01   VEG         2
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(CRP = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B"), SSN = c("S01", 
"S01", "S01", "S01", "S02", "S02", "S03"), PLT = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L), PARAM = c("GER", "GER", "VEG", "VEG", "GER", 
"GER", "GER"), VAL = c(NA, NA, 40L, 41L, 100L, 90L, 90L)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```